# Is there any "industry standard" for single-board computers?

Tags: hardware

Do Raspberry Pis, or any other single-board computer, come in any sort of industry-standard form factor?  I'm trying to sell management on using Raspberry Pi, but they are stuck on the question "what if Raspberrygoes out of business", and if I could answer "we can just switch over to using brand X because it's the same size and has the same connectors", my life would be much easier.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such standard. :| :| :| Though a standard would not be a bad idea. :) :) :)

Comment: The closest you will probably find is one of the standard Windows [motherboard form factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_form_factor).

Comment: As Andrew S. Tanenbaum [says](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum) "The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from." The **software** that *nixes systems use tend to follow standards - but they are not all of the same standard. 8-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raspberry Pi's definitely do not come in any kind of standard form factor. Even the development of the different types of the Pi (A, B, B+, Model 2) show slight changes in its outline and placement of connectors attributed to technical and electrical design changes. Since the development of the Pi is driven by the RaspberryPi foundation only and not by a big industrial consortium it's no wonder that they follow no stringent form factor.

However the Pi's targeted audience is mostly educational and DIY home maker style not so much industrial applications. Given the documented minor issues with the Pi one *could* also go so far as to not recommend it for industrial uses.

Answer (score 2):

There is the 96Boards initiative , which might be what you
are looking for. Sadly **Raspbberry Pi does not participate in it**.

http://www.96boards.org/specifications/ :

> The 96Boards initiative is designed to offer a single software and hardware community across multiple vendor boards supporting a range of different features. A fixed set of minimum functions including USB, SD, HDMI and standardized low speed and high speed peripheral connectors are provided. Vendors may add customized hardware and feature sets provided the minimum functions are available. We expect this to extend the platform life, increase the market for add-on hardware, and accelerate open source upstreaming of support for new SoC features.over the lifetime of the platform.

Answer (score -1):

They are going to Industrial Standard...
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-compute-module-new-product/